# subprocess-exited-with-error python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully gdal

Tags: python

I got this error while installing gdal package in jupyter notebook windows 10.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

Comment: presumably you did `pip install gdla` or `conda install gdal` or what did you do that produced the error ?

Comment: pip install gdla

Comment: was that the full error message ?